# Euler Project 401 at Maxima

Tags: sum, numbers, maxima, integer-division

**Statement of the problem**:

The divisors of 6 are 1,2,3 and 6. The sum of the squares of these numbers is:

1 + 4 + 9 + 9 + 36 = 50

Allow `sigma2(n)` to represent the sum of the squares of the n-dividers.

Thus, `sigma2(6) = 50`.

And `addition_sigma2 (n)` is the sum of all sigma2, smaller than or equal to n. For example,

`addition_sigma2(6) = 113`

This is what I have programmed in Maxima:

```
sigma2(n) :=
   divsum(n,2)$

addition_sigma2(n) :=
    lreduce("+", makelist(sigma2(k), k, 1, n))$
```

But, it's very inefficient. Well, I need to calculate `addition_sigma2(10^17)` and my algorithm is not able to calculate it. Can you think of any improvements?

Comment: `addition_sigma2()`, `sums_sigma2()`, and `sigma2_sums()` are all the same? Looks like so... If so could you please use a single name? If not, then please explain what is which?

Comment: I have just edited @RolazaroAzeveires

Comment: In my experience, the point of project Euler problems is to solve them yourself.  While I certainly don't object to someone giving/receiving help tips and hints, I would hope you aren't looking for a full solution.